# NullPointerException error with Intent

Tags: android-intent, nullpointerexception

I got null pointer exception error right after I click button1. But I'm not sure what is the route cause. Could someone help me?

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener());
}
class ButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v){
        EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText address = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);

        Spinner month = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.month);
        Spinner day = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.day);

        RadioGroup radio = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.gendar);
        RadioButton radiobutton=
                (RadioButton)findViewById(radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

        CheckBox applecheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.applecheck);
        CheckBox orangecheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.orangecheck);
        CheckBox peachcheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.peachcheck);

        EditText appleqty = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.appleqty);
        EditText orangeqty = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.orangeqty);
        EditText peachqty = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.peachqty);

        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("NAME", name.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("ADDRESS", address.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("MONTH",month.getSelectedItem().toString());
        intent.putExtra("DAY", day.getSelectedItem().toString());
        intent.putExtra("GENDAR", radiobutton.getText().toString());
        if(applecheck.isChecked())
            intent.putExtra("APPLE", appleqty.getText().toString());
        if(orangecheck.isChecked())
            intent.putExtra("ORANGE", orangeqty.getText().toString());
        if(peachcheck.isChecked())
            intent.putExtra("PEACH", peachqty.getText().toString());

        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

}

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Bundle extra= getIntent().getExtras();

    String name = extra.getString("NAME");
    String address = extra.getString("ADDRESS");
    String month = extra.getString("MONTH");
    String day = extra.getString("DAY");
    String gendar = extra.getString("GENDAR");
    String apple = extra.getString("APPLE");
    String orange = extra.getString("ORANGE");
    String peach = extra.getString("PEACH");
```

11-11 14:38:38.681: E/AndroidRuntime(363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 14:38:38.681: E/AndroidRuntime(363): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 14:38:38.681: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.example.sample4_3.FirstActivity$ButtonClickListener.onClick(FirstActivity.java:34)
11-11 14:38:38.681: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
11-11 14:38:38.681: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
11-11 14:38:38.681: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-11 14:38:38.681: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-11 14:38:38.681: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-11 14:38:38.681: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-11 14:38:38.681: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 14:38:38.681: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-11 14:38:38.681: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

New error I'm having is as follows;
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sample4_3/com.example.sample4_3.SecondActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #126: Error inflating class textView
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #126: Error inflating class textView
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at com.example.sample4_3.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:14)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  ... 11 more
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.textView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.sample4_3-2.apk]
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
11-11 16:24:39.680: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  ... 23 more

Well, I can not find how to fix this error even I checked line #126.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you highlight line 34. But from what I can readily tell from your code, in `ButtonClickListener`, you are accessing `findViewById` without using the view that is passed in as a parameter. I am not sure why thats not the error as you should not be able to do that. The other thing that could be the issue is that `R.id.button1` could be misspelled, or its misspelled in the xml.

Comment: thank you for your response. I found what is the error and facing new error. The error was I forgot to add manifest file about Intent. but now I'm facing new error. Well It might be difficult to get help on this site but I upload error on eclipse as above.

Comment: Oh. Was the error what I told you or something else? And did you fix the new error?

Comment: Thank you very much. It was you pointed out and code for intent in Manifest. But now new one. I can not put the error so I will put error log above.

Comment: Thank you very much, Andy. It was also as you mentioned. The letter was miss spelled(lower case) and some missed parameter in xml such "layout_height". Now It works.